# DocuSign document uri for user

Tags: docusignapi

Issue 1 - Now I am using Code Grant and fetched token with refresh token, still it is not working, next day when I am using same token generated with refresh_token is giving error

Issue 2- How can I get uri or path of that file - so that user can click that link - view status - download ?

like `https://demo.docussing.com/accountid/envelopeid/documentid` some thing like this, once user click on that page it will open that page showing current state of document

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow is best used as one-topic-per-question. When asking, it's best to provide as much detail as possible about what you're doing, what's wrong, what errors are received, and what you've tried to do to investigate.

For issue 1, access tokens last for eight hours, so when an access token expires you will need to generate a new one. Based on your question, I'm not sure that's happening - Are you able to use the refresh token to generate new access token, or is that what's failing?

For issue 2, there are a few ways to approach. First, your application could directly download the PDF of the envelope (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/) and display that. If you would like to take the sender to a DocuSign interface to allow them to view the envelope, there are various Recipient View calls that may be of use: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/

I would recommend testing the SenderView call to see if that meets your needs. An alternative would be the RecipientView call, which can be used with the sender's name and email in the call body to get to a read-only view of the envelope.